# Moving start of text to correct indentation

Tags: vimrc

A lot of times in vim I will copy-paste in some text, and it will not be at the correct level of indentation. Here is a sort of example:

[image]

Is there a command I can run on one or more lines (other than successively typing `<<` or `>>`) that can move the text to the correct level of indentation, i.e., what the indentation would be if I pressed `o` or `O` ?

Comment: `A lot of times in vim I will copy-paste in some text, and it will not be at the correct level of indentation.` Use `]p` instead of `p`

Comment: @Matt -- take for example, I copy text that is indented 5 lines, and then I paste it where it should only be indented 3 lines...Or I copy something from the web which starts with 5 tabs or whatever. In other words, if we disregard the "pasting" aspect into it is it possible to indent that line to the place where "o" would have put it?

Comment: `]p` to put text and fix indent at the same time; `[count]==` to filter existing lines through `'equalprg'` (or built-in indentation procedure) which normally should be enough to make things rolling.

Comment: Does running the command `V=` in Normal Mode indent the line correctly in your environment?

Answer (score 1):

The Python indentation code that ships with Vim makes decisions on some lines, such as increasing indent on lines that follow one that ends with `:` (which marks the start of a block) and also lines that are continuations (detecting whether the expression has open parens or braces that still need to be closed.) It also reduces indentation in some specific cases (for example `else`, `elif`, `except` and `finally` statements, that should align with the original start of the block.)

But the Python indentation code *purposefully* doesn't meddle with indentation in most other cases.

That's somewhat understandable, since indentation is significant in Python, so it's not always possible to guess the indentation correctly in all cases.

Consider, for example, these three lines:

```
if condition:
command1()
command2()
```

Now it's evident that `command1()` needs to be indented, but it's not obvious whether `command2()` should belong to the same block or not.

This is one possible interpretation of this sequence:

```
if condition:
    command1()
    command2()
```

But this is also a possible valid indentation, though with a different meaning:

```
if condition:
    command1()
command2()
```

So the Python indentation code decides it's best not to make a decision in such cases, where it can't really guess which one is right. Perhaps in the vein of "do no harm".

Having said that, the interpretation below of the code above is clearly invalid:

```
if condition:
    command1()
        command2()
```

That is, a line should not be indented *further* than the line above, unless it fits into some specific cases, such as the line above ending with `:` or it being a continuation line.

This one matches your example.

Since `GetPythonIndent()` already gets all the cases where indentation should be increased right, you could override it not to allow this specific situation, with a separate indentation function like the one below:

```
function! GetOpinionatedPythonIndent()
  let result = GetPythonIndent(v:lnum)
  if result == -1
    let lastindent = indent(prevnonblank(v:lnum-1))
    if indent(v:lnum) > lastindent
      let result = lastindent
    endif
  endif
  return result
endfunction

setlocal indentexpr=GetOpinionatedPythonIndent()
```

Note that this uses the original `GetPythonIndent()`, but overrides it in some of the cases where it doesn't make a decision (when it returns -1), by ensuring the current line's indentation will not be *higher* than the last previous non-blank line.

Independently of those, you should also get familiar with the keystrokes you can use in Insert mode to control indentation of a particular line. Yes, you have the `<<`, `>>` and `==` Normal mode commands, but you don't really need to exit Insert mode to adjust the indentation of the current line, using the equivalent commands:

- [`CTRL-D`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-D): Delete one shiftwidth of indent at the start of the current line.  The indent is always rounded to a `'shiftwidth'` (this is vi compatible). (This does the same as `<<` in Normal mode.)
- [`CTRL-T`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-T): Insert one shiftwidth of indent at the start of the current line.  The indent is always rounded to a `'shiftwidth'` (this is vi compatible). (This does the same as `>>` in Normal mode.)
- [`CTRL-F`](https://vimhelp.org/indent.txt.html#i_CTRL-F) is typically included in `'indentkeys'` or `'cinkeys'` to trigger `'indentexpr'` or `'cindent'` on the current line, which typically matches what the `==` Normal mode command does.

The latter `CTRL-F` is not very useful for the Python indentation, for the same reason why `=` doesn't really fix these lines in the first place, but using `CTRL-D` can be helpful and perhaps a bit more convenient than `<<`.

Additionally, there's even use `0 CTRL-D` or `^ CTRL-D` in Insert mode (!) to remove all indentation from the current line. It's not too useful in Python, but it's quite useful in languages like C where you might want to use a `#ifdef` for a block of code, or otherwise when you want to add a label for a `goto` or similar statement.a

Answer (score 0):

To auto-indent you can use the `=` command.

A few examples:

- `gg=G` : go to top (`gg`), and indent (`=`) until end of file (`G`).
- `==` : indent a line
- `=ip` : indent the inner paragraph

If you just want to paste with the correct level of indentation:

- `[p` : paste above
- `]p` : paste below

Comment: thanks, though none of those commands helped.

Comment: Well, it should, though. Could you share your config?

Comment: To be fair, I have issues with the python indenter, so I just run the file through Black on save.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Strange, I have no problem whatsoever with Python. How can I check the indenter I'm using?

Comment: @Biggybi If you want to check on-the-fly indent then `set indentexpr?` and `verbose fun GetPythonIndent` or whatever shows nidentexpr; to check what is current "equal" operator execute `set equalprg?`

Comment: @Matt thank you. So, `equalprg` is empty, and `indentxpr` is indeed GetPythonIndent. Not sure it's helpful... might be.