# Customizing Tabbing and backspace properties in vim

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

There are two features related to indenting that I find very helpful in Textmate, and I'm looking to find the closest thing in vim. First, I can <kbd>tab</kbd> to the correct level of indentation, especially in python. For example:

[image]

[After hitting tab once]

[image]

On the other hand (assuming all space-chars to the left of the cursor), using backspace in Textmate goes back a full tab-stop if it is "on" a tab or a space until it hits an even tab (for example, if tabwidth=4 and I am at column 6, pressing backspace would go to 5, then 4, then 0. Here is an example video of the two: https://gyazo.com/2f1d2731a9d243448350b942eac29524

What would be the closest way to emulate this behavior in vim? I feel like it would only be most relevant in insert mode.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the images, you want 4 spaces for <kbd>tab</kbd>.
Put the following in your `.vimrc`:

```
set tabstop=4                         " Redefine tab as four spaces
set softtabstop=4                     " Number of spaces in tab when editing
set shiftwidth=4                      " To change the number of space characters inserted for indentation
set autoindent                        " Auto indent
set smartindent                       " Does the right thing (mostly) in programs
filetype indent plugin on             " Enables filetype detection, add after all plugins if using Vundle
```

`softtabstop=4` takes care of the backspace property that you demand. Other settings in the above are for indentation. With `shiftwidth=4`, `autoindent` and `smartindent` indentation in python will be taken care of I think, vim will automatically determine filetype (`filetype indent plugin on`) and add required number of tabs while you are editing your file.

If further, you want each <kbd>tab</kbd>-press to introduce 4 actual spaces in your document, you should further add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
set expandtab                         " Four spaces for tabs everywhere
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1878983/9445700.

Answer (score 1):

1. The indentation level is automatically adjust (given that you have `set autoindent` and such) upon entering Normal mode commands `o`, `O`, `S`, `cc` etc. If, for some reason, you're already in Insert mode on empty line #4, you still can press `<Esc>S`. However, the chances are you're misusing Vim, because you violate the rules (a) leave from the Insert mode ASAP; and (b) use the most appropriate Normal mode command to re-enter it. Therefore you should (almost) never see the picture #1 in Vim.
2. An indentation level is changed by `<{motion}`, `>{motion}`, `[count]<<` and `[count]>>` in Normal mode, and `{Visual}>` and `{Visual}<`in Visual mode. Specifically for Insert mode there are also `<C-D>` and `<C-T>`.

That should be enough to deal with this thing, however, if you really miss that "backspace" you can try to emulate such behaviour. For example,

```
inoremap <expr><BS> searchpos('^\s*\%#', 'bn')[1] ? '<C-D>' : '<BS>'
```

That is, if there are only spaces and tabs before the cursor position then use `<C-D>` instead of `<BS>`.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question:

> First, I can Tab to the correct level of indentation, especially in python.

In Vim you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to trigger automatic indentation, be it through `'indentexpr'` or `'cindent'`.

(This is usually implemented by adding the `^F` key to `'indentkeys'` or `'cinkeys'`. See [`:help i_CTRL-F`](https://vimhelp.org/indent.txt.html#i_CTRL-F) for more details.)

For your specific Python example, it works exactly as you describe it.

But remember that Vim's Python indentation will [only set indentation for selected lines](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/25526/18609), such as those following a line ending in `:` or a line with a keyword such as `else:` or `elif:` which needs to be dedented from the block that precedes it. So <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> will only work on those lines that Python indentation will have an opinion on. That's the case with this particular line, which follows a `for` statement. But it won't indent you to a block if it's to match a simple command that's there, in that case you'll have to indent manually (with Tab or CTRL+T) or use `o` in Normal mode to have `'autoindent'` keep same indentation as the preceding line.